# Azure Pipelines - Packages are using versioning from pre-release task rather than release task despite pre-release task not running

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

Basically, I have a pipeline that is pushing packages to a feed.  I have it set to use environment variables to create a pre-release package version if the source is `development` branch. Otherwise, it should read the versioning from the `.csproj` file if the source branch is `master`. According to the logs, the correct steps are running. However, when I get to the `push` step, I notice in the logs that it's pushing a pre-release rather than the release to the feed despite the pre-release task not even running.  What's going on and how can I fix this? Here are the tasks in question:

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  isDev: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/development')]
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Dotnet Pack"
  condition: eq(variables.isMain, true)
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Dotnet Pack (pre-release)"
  condition: eq(variables.isDev, true)
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: PackageVersion

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'Nuget Push to Feed'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '*cleared*'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

Comment: I can't see how `isMain` and `isDev` are calculated. It would seem based on your pipeline that for this to work, those values have to be mutually exclusive. Is it possible that you're running into a condition where there's not the case? If you add a `pwsh` or `script` task above this that dumps out the values of those variables, are you running into a case where they're both true?

Comment: I added the variables.

Comment: It might be useful to see the log output for the push?

Comment: Based on the logs, it's skipping the `pre-release` task and executing the `Dotnet Pack` task but when I go to the `Nuget Push to Feed` step, I can clearly see it says that's it's pushing the `pre-release` version of the `.nupkg`.

Comment: Understood, it's just that I can't offer too much more insight without actually seeing the log output (might not even then, but I'm flying blind at the moment).

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla That's interesting. I can't quite tell what the issue is yet. Would you be kind enough to post your logs and your full YAML pipeline?

Comment: Hi @TheVanillaThrilla. I have tested your yaml sample and reproduce the same issue. This issue is related with the variable name. Please refer to my answer. Feel free to let me know if it could solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I get to the push step, I notice in the logs that it's pushing a pre-release rather than the release to the feed despite the pre-release task not even running.

Based on my test, I could reproduce this issue when I run the pipeline with your Yaml Pipeline sample.

[image]

The root cause of this issue is the name of the environment variable **PackageVersion**.

When the environment variable name is PackageVersion, this issue will exist.

To solve this issue, you could change the environment variable name.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Dotnet Pack (pre-release)"
  condition: eq(variables.isDev, true)
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: byEnvVar
    versionEnvVar: Package1
```

Then it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: Sorry Kevin, just saw this response. I haven't had a chance to test this, but why would the name of the environment variable matter? Is it a pre-defined variable name or something?

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla According to my test, this variable name will force to override the version number in the file. You could try my solution in the answer. If you change the variable name, it will work fine.